# conda: possibility to specify one-of requirements?

Tags: conda

I wonder is it possible to specify one-of requirements in a conda recipe? something like

```yaml
- package_foo || package_bar
```

which would be satisfied if either dependency is installed, and otherwise install the leftmost one.

What I'm intending to do is a more specific use case though: restricting a package to a set of channels, e.g.

```yaml
- channel_a::package || channel_b::package
```

Is this possible? I skimmed the docs but couldn't find anything...